# How do I get an id from a student in a list and display it the student's information on another page? Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a list of students and when I click on one of the hyperlinks, I want to display a table with the student's information I clicked on.

I am working with two pages, **index.html.erb** and **show.html.erb**. In the index page, I want to display the list and the show page, I want to display the information for only one student. I am very new to Ruby on Rails, but I want to get better at it. Thank for all your responses.

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1> Welcome </h1>

   <%= link_to "Display Table", students_show_path %>
   <%= link_to "Form", students_new_path %>

<ol> Students
    <% @student.each do |s| %>
       <!--<li><%= link_to s.FirstName, students_show_path(@student.students_id), method: :post %> </li> -->
       <li><%= link_to s.FirstName, :action => "show", :id => Student.id %> </li>
   <% end %>
</ol>
```

**This is my show.html.erb**

## Table's Page

```
<% @student.each do |s| %>
<tr>
    <td> <%= s.FirstName %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.LastName %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.NickName %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.EmailAddress %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.Birthday %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.MedicalNotes %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.Grade %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.School %> </td>
    <td> <%= s.Gender %> </td>
</tr>
```

**This is my routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'students#index'
  get 'students/index'
  get 'students/show'
  get 'students/new'
  get 'students/update'
  get 'students/create'
  get 'students/edit'
  get 'students/destroy'
  get '/signup', to: 'students#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'students#create'
  post '/index', to: 'students#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

resources :students
  # generates:
  #   get "/students" -- index on your controller
  #   get "/students/:id" -- show on your controller
  #   get "/students/new" -- new method on your controller
  #   post "/students" -- create on your controller
  #   get "/students/:id/edit" -- edit method on your controller
  #   put "/students/:id" -- update on your controller
  #   patch "/students/:id" -- update on your controller
  #   delete "/students/:id" -- destroy on your controller
end
```

**This is my students_controller**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @student = Student.all
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @student = Student.where("Student id = ?" , "#{id}")
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def update
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
      redirect_to students_show_path
    else
      render 'new'
  end
end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def student_params
       params.permit(:FirstName, :LastName, :NickName, :EmailAddress, :Birthday, :MedicalNotes, :Grade, :School, :Gender)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing:

The Ruby way to name attributes, methods, and variables is to use snake_case. For example, `s.FirstName` should be `s.first_name`. In Ruby, if the name is capitalized like `FirstName` it is actually a constant. This style is called CamelCase and it is the conventional way to name classes in Ruby e.g. `StudentsController`.

For the `routes.rb`:

Rails will generate all of the RESTful routes and helper methods for your resource if you use

```
resources :students
```

you can then view all of these routes by running `rake routes` on the command line or visiting `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` in the browser. You can learn more info about routes in the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes

You can then use the Rails `link_to` helper method like this:

```
<%= link_to s.first_name, s %>
```

and Rails will figure out the `id` of the object for you. Or if you want to be more explicit:

```
<%= link_to s.first_name, student_path(s.id) %>
```

And in the `show` action of your `StudentsController` you want:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end
```

this will look up the student record in the database based on the `:id` parameter in the URL for student show page

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Zack. I tried doind that, but I got this error: **undefined method `each' for #<Student:0xde38058>** on my show page. I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: @CristianUPolanco In your controller if you changed the method from `where` to `find`, it's going to return a singular object rather than an array. `where` will be an array, which has an `each` method (even if it contains only one item). If you're using `find` then just remove the `each` block and reference it directly like `@student`

Comment: I found a way around it, but thanks for the info. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For your index.html.erb file, try updating the link_to helpers to something like:

```
<%= link_to s, s.FirstName %>
```

You don't need to pass the full route + ID if using link helpers with the show method, rails will automagically link for you.

Remove all of the `get 'students/...` routes, just leave the `resources: :students`. The routes you're specifying above this line are redundant.

Your `show` method in the controller can also be cleaned up slightly:

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end
```

And finally, I believe in your `create` method, you can redirect using just the resource:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)
  if @student.save
    redirect_to @student
  else
    render 'new'
end
```

Comment: It's not just cleaned up slightly, `find` has a different return signature than `where`

Comment: So, how would I link from one page to the other now that I do not have **student_show_path** and so on?

Comment: @CristianUPolanco You still have the routes, they are being generated by `resources: :students` (You can type `rake routes` in the console to confirm). The line `link_to @something, 'my link` is the same as writing `link_to 'my_link', something_show_path(@something.id)`. The other routes, like student_edit_path, can still be used.

Comment: @DivXZero thanks for telling me that. After a lot of pocking around and thanks to Zack, I was able to pass the id of the user to the show page. I am still getting another error haha, but I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice about your code

1)

```
get 'students/show'
```

To be able to retrieve an user, you need a user id, a unique identifier. So your show route should contain an id. The Rails way is something like this

```
get 'students/:id'
```

I'm simplyfing here because your route could work if you call it with your param in query string (`'students/show?id=something'`)

Anyway, you are defining every route in a different line. It turns out that you can define all of them with just the line

```
resources :students
```

2)

In your show action you want just one user. And you have an id, and that's unique, so you can use it to directly retrieve your user

```
def show
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
end
```

You used `where` and that's for retrieve ALL the user that match your condition (maybe you want to retrieve every user whose first name is 'John'). So it turns out your `@user` doesn't contain directly one user, but your user in a relation. That's because `where`.

Comment: thanks for telling me that. I thought that `where` worked the same way as in MySQL where I could just choose one user if I wanted to.

Comment: Not exactly. For Rails one user or a collection of user is different. Even if that collection is of one element :)